# How I redirect from controller to twig view in slim framework?

Tags: twig, slim

How I redirect from controller to view in slim?

```
class ServiceController{

    $app = new \Slim\App;
    $mw = function ($request, $response, $next) {

                    $response->withHeader('/twig/html/home.twig');
                    return $response;
    };
    $app->run();
}
```

Comment: what are u trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I generally want to render view from controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look at the [Documentation (Slim 3)](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html) for rendering a template, there is the `render`-method on the view object.

Slim 3

```
$app->get('/Home', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($response, '/twig/html/home.twig');
});
```

Slim 2 ([Documentation for Slim 2](http://docs.slimframework.com/view/rendering/))

```
$app->get('/Home', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('/twig/html/home.twig');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an actual redirect (as opposed to a rendering a view) as I was when I found this question, you can use the `->withRedirect('url/goes/here')` method on the response object like so:

```
$app->post('/login', function ($request, $response) {
    return $response->withRedirect('/home');
});
```